# How to load URL in android Web View if HTTP or HTTPS not include in given URL

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an project where I want to load some url came from webservice into a webView but. for that I am facing the following problem. Please help.

```
url = "www.facebook.com"
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

for above code I got an error say unable load webpage.

But if i changed this to

```
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
```

its working but I need to load url without having http or https mentioned .

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

add this by your own code like

```
    String urlCameFromServer = "www.facebook.com";
    if(!urlCameFromServer.contains("http")) {
         urlCameFromServer = "http://"+urlCameFromServer;
    }
    wv.loadUrl(urlCameFromServer);
```

Comment: I can't do this because if server is not in http the it will also return error.

Comment: most of the services that requires `https` has redirect form `http` to `https`